# Changing background colour of poster

Tags: color, backgrounds, posters

I want to change the background color of my poster but whatever command I try, nothing changes.

I am using this poster: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/baposter-landscape-poster.

This was included in the poster template:

```
\newcommand{\baposter@backgroundCmd}{\error{No background command defined. Use \background{...} to define background}}
\newcommand{\background}[1]{\renewcommand{\baposter@backgroundCmd}{#1}}
```

So I thought `\background` might work, it did not.

These are the relevant packages:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be beyond ideal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a *full* MWE.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy with one-colour background it is quite simple:

```
\definecolor{BGcolour}{RGB}{40,40,40} % Define the colour named BGcolour
\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
% other options
bgColorOne=BGcolour, % declare background colour
background=plain,    % set background to be plain colour
% other options}

% Poster code

\end{document}
```

---

Personal sidenotes:
Be carefull about transparency in your figures!
Be carefull about text and graphics colour match to the background!
I think that in most cases plain white (`background=none`) background and matte paper is the best option.

Comment: Maybe an addition to the careful-list: printing a poster with coloured background will consume a lot more ink.

Comment: @samcarter True, but printing costs are, in my opinion, negligible to readability and aesthetical result. White background is both clean and cheap :)

Comment: when I put this into my code I get an error like this: Runaway argument?
{ 
Paragraph ended before \XKV@ifcmd was complete. I do not know why it keeps coming up especially when I do not know what this XKV file is..

Comment: @cameron What have you changed to get rid off the error. And note that `code emphasis` works here too. And add your code before asking.